# Creating New Variables Conditional on Others [sas]

Tags: sas

The original dataset is like:

```
sub month y
1   1     1
1   2     2
1   3     3
1   5     5
```

What I want is to get the previous 3 ys based on month for each subject, if y is missing at that month, then the new variable is `.` too. Say , for the above example, lag1 is previous `y` for last month, `lag2` is previous y for 2 months ago, the `lag3` is so far so forth:

```
sub month y lag1 lag2 lag3
1   1     1  .    .    .
1   2     2  1    .    .
1   3     3  2    1    .
1   5     5  .    3    2
```

The thing is I checked out `lag` and `dif` function, but in my case, what I want on `lag` depends on `month` and there also are gaps between month, so I can not use the previous one like `lag1` function.

Also  I need to do this for many subjects too. Thanks.

Comment: What does "lag depends on time" mean?  I don't see a variable named "time".  Also, is the second data block exactly the result you want, given the original dataset?

Comment: @BobDuell I am sorry for confusion. I just changed the variable `time` to `month` to make my question clearer. Yes, Second one is what I want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you want to do.  In what way does "lag2" equal "3" for the fourth obs?  Is it because of the gap in month (as if there had been a row with "month=4")?

Comment: So for obs4 : "month = 5", lag2 is the y two month ago, which is the y at month=3; lag3 is the y three months ago, which is the y at month=2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL solution:

```
data have;
input sub month y;
datalines;
1   1     1
1   2     2
1   3     3
1   5     5 
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
    select H.sub,H.month, H.y, One.y as lag1, Two.y as lag2, Three.y as lag3
    from have H
    left join (select * from have) One on H.sub=One.sub and H.month=One.month+1
    left join (select * from have) Two on H.sub=two.sub and H.month=Two.month+2
    left join (select * from have) Three on H.sub=three.sub and H.month=Three.month+3
;
quit;
```

Obviously this gets a bit long if you want 36 of them, but it's not all that complex at least.  There are all sorts of other ways to do this.  Don't use LAG, that's going to be a headache and not really appropriate anyway.  A hash table might be more efficient and require less coding, if you're familiar with the concept of a hash.

Hash solution:

```
data want;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
 declare hash h(dataset:'have(rename=y=ly)');
 h.defineKey('sub','month');
 h.defineData('ly');
 h.defineDone();
 call missing(sub,month,ly);
end;
set have;
array lags lag1-lag3;
do prevmonth = month-1 to month-3 by -1;
  if prevmonth le 0 then leave;
  rc=h.find(key:sub,key:prevmonth);
  if rc=0 then lags[month-prevmonth] = ly;
  call missing(ly);
end;
run;
```

This is pretty simple to expand up to 36 [or whatever] - just change the length of the array to `array lags lag1-lag36` and the do statement `do prevmonth=month-1 to month-36 by -1;`  The most work you may have to do is arrange things so month works here - either by creating a integer month, or changing the loop criteria to work with month/year or whatnot.  You don't show how your data is specified so can't help there.

Comment: Nice.  Don't see the reason for the derived tables in your SQL suggestion; a simple join seems sufficient.